# How do i check if there is spaces in textBox content?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have this code :

```
private void BtnScrambleText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
            BtnScrambleText.Enabled = false;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            var words = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(words[i]))
                {
                    sb.Append(words[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    ScrambleTextBoxText scrmbltb = new ScrambleTextBoxText(words[i]);
                    scrmbltb.GetText();
                    sb.Append(scrmbltb.scrambledWord);
                }
            }
            textBox2.AppendText(sb.ToString());
        }
```

For example in `textBox1` i did typed pressed the space bar key 7 times and then typed some words and then 5 spaces again and a word:

```
danny hi hello daniel     hello
```

So lets say danny is after 7 spaces from the beginning in `textBox1` and between daniel and hello there are more 5 spaces.

In my code i did:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(words[i]))
{
    sb.Append(words[i]);
}
```

But that never will happen and its not right.
I wanted to check that if before or after a word in the textBox there is any space/s add the space/s to the sb variable.

So in the end `textBox2` content will be the same as in `textBox1` with the same number of spaces between the words.

Now `textBox2` looks like a long one string of words without any spaces between them.

My problem is how to add the same spaces between the words from `textBox1` ?

Comment: If you save the Textbox content to a variable, spaces will also be stored, so you will not have problem assigning it to Textbox1

Comment: If you want the same content in both `textboxes` then why don't you aimply do this `textbox2.text = textbox1.text` ?

Comment: `foreach(var c in textBox1.Text) {...}` if `c` is not a character, just add it to `sb`. if it is, "collect" it and all the upcoming characters in a seperate variable until you reach the next non-character. Then scramble the collected characters and add them to `sb`. (Assuming you want the second textbox have the exact same string as the first one, but with randomized characters for each word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is absolutely useless:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(words[i]))
{
    sb.Append(words[i]);
}
```

It seems you need something like this (not tested):

```
private void BtnScrambleText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Enabled = false;
    BtnScrambleText.Enabled = false;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var words = Regex.Split(textBox1.Text, @"(?=(?<=[^\s])\s+)");
    foreach (string word  in words)
    {
        ScrambleTextBoxText scrmbltb = new ScrambleTextBoxText(word.Trim());
        scrmbltb.GetText();
        sb.Append(word.Replace(word.Trim(), scrmbltb.scrambledWord));
    }
    textBox2.AppendText(sb.ToString());
}
```

`Regex.Split(textBox1.Text, @"(?=(?<=[^\s])\s+)")` splits the input string with preserving spaces.

Comment: Andrey Your code example just add a space in textBox2 between each word. But i wanted to add the same number of spaces between the words like in textBox1. If in textBox1 somewhere in the content between two words there are 7 spaces then it should be between the two words also in textBox2 no one space but seven !

Answer (score 3):

I simplified your code a little, but you should find it easy to apply in your situation. The problem comes from the fact that you are losing the spaces when you do the split and they are not being added back in. The solution is to use "String.Join" when you have the finished collection of strings. In this case since you know the output size is the same as the input size, I don't see any reason to use the stringbuilder. Just use an array you size to the input.

```
string inputText = "This is a test";

        var words = inputText.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        var outputWords = new string[words.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(words[i]))
            {
                outputWords[i] = words[i];
            }
            else
            {
                outputWords[i] = Scramble(words[i]);
            }
        }

        string outputText = string.Join(" ",outputWords);
```

Answer (score 1):

This the easy form

```
string text=mytextbox.Text;
while(text.Contains("  ")) //while two spaces
  text=text.Replace("  "," "); //remove two spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

If i got it right, your problem is to keep the exact number of spaces between the then scrambled words.

```
var words = string.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.None); // this keeps the spaces as "epmty words"
var scrambled = words.Select(w => { if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(w))
                                          return w;
                                    else {
                                         ScrambleTextBoxText scrmbltb = new ScrambleTextBoxText(w);
                                         scrmbltb.GetText();
                                         return scrmbltb.scrambledWord;
                                    }
                                  });
var result = string.Join(" ", scrambled);
```

Comment: Yes you got the idea the problem.

Comment: okrumnow two errors first in the line with the StringSplitOptions im getting the error Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.StringSplitOptions' to 'char' and second in the instance of the new class ScrambleTextBoxText scrmbltb = new ScrambleTextBoxText(words[i]); the variable i is not exist

Comment: This is basically the same solution as the one from @Xenophile, but using Linq.

Comment: @HaimKashi I edited the code. Either omit the StringSplitOptions parameter (it defaults to None) or use an char[] as first parameter.

Comment: @okrumnow: Yeah I like linq. I just didn't want to introduce what might be a new concept in the middle of an explanation.